# Is it safe to feed an adult fire salamander with slime maggots?

Tags: zoology, digestive-system, pets

As a reminder, maggots feed of a flesh, while fire salamander consumes his prey alive, without killing it.
Can it happen that the maggot will start eating the salamander from the inside?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is off-topic for Biology, and instead should be posted at [pets.se].

Comment: Maggots typically eat dead/rotting flesh, not live. [Maggot therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggot_therapy) is used in clinical settings in the US and around the world for debridement of necrotic wounds.

Comment: @MATTDMo reluctantly I can see your point. I feel it could be edited into a more general question about ingesting live larvae that would be on-topic for Biology though - OP, would you have any objection to that?

Comment: @arboviral no objections, since i've got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am afraid I don't know much about fire salamanders specifically, it is certainly possible for ingested fly larvae (or larvae hatching from ingested eggs) to survive ingestion and subsequently cause intestinal damage. Parasitic infestation by fly larvae that grow inside the host while feeding on its tissue is called [myiasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myiasis). Enteric myiasis (also called gastric, rectal, or intestinal myiasis to indicate the affected part of the digestive system) occurs occasionally in humans following the ingestion of cheese infested with [cheese fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piophilidae) maggots. [Casu marzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casu_marzu), a traditionally produced Sardinian cheese, is *supposed* to have live cheese fly maggots in it, and cases of bloody diarrhoea following its consumption are known. If they're dead the cheese is considered unsafe to eat (although personally I'd correct that to 'more unsafe').